# How can I cluster about 500000 strings

Tags: python, string, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have about 500000 strings and I want to cluster them in groups. Is there a webportal or webservice I can use to do that ?

The strings are unique.
I need to group them into groups based on similarity.

Any other means?

Comment: What do you mean by clustering? What's your goal and the purpose of this? What are those strings? Please provide more information.

Comment: If you want to count the number of strings there are use a dictionary with each string as a key. This is assuming the number of redundancies are high

Comment: string similarity is an extremely broad topic, first of all are those just single words or sentences/paragraphs? What do you mean by "similar", do you mean semantically similar or edit distance similar (for instance typos)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to cluster a lis of strings (words) into similarity groups you would need to tell if you need to find words where similar edit (Levenshtein) distance appears in the same cluster. For instance you would say "algorithm" and "alogrithm" should have high chances to appear in the same cluster.

State of art recommend using graph clustering algorithms like

- Louvain clustering
- Restricted Neighbourhood Search Clustering (RNSC)
- [Affinity Propgation Clustering (APC)](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/315/5814/972.short)
- Markov Cluster algorithm
  (MCL).

Comment: You don't want to run APC on 500000 objects... and probably some of the others will require O(n^2) memory, too.

Comment: MCL requires O(n*k) memory, where k is the number of nodes that are kept track of. In the default setting this is 1400. MCL scales easily to millions of nodes if you know what you are doing - in bioinformatics it is routinely used to cluster graphs with 8M+ nodes, admittedly on chunky hardware. More generally, in graph clustering one does not work with a complete graph / all-vs-all matrix / O(n^2) memory. Some filtering or thresholding is used to restrict the number of neighbours per node. How this is done is best seen as an issue that is separate from the clustering.